# How to Open the Explorer on the Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to open the windiws explorer using c# in windows 11 but the File Explorer opens briefly and then closes without displaying the window while still showing in the task manager, please help me to solve

NB: The same code working perfectly in Windows 10

```
var myFile = "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe";
var workingFolder = "C:\\Windows";
var process = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.FileName = myFile;
process.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;
process.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Arguments = "d:\\";
Process.Start(process);
```

Comment: asp.net? are you trying to open the client’s explorer through a webpage/browser?

Comment: Nothing changed in Windows 11. Starting Windows Explorer works just fine. You don't even need to specify the full path because `explorer.exe` is always in the system path. If you tried to do this in a web app, it wasn't working no matter what you assumed. Once you deployed your code on a web server you'd realize that Explorer starts only on the web server, under the application pool's account and is only visible in the app pool desktop.